# Jquery UI accordion - Open two tabs in a controler

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to open two tabs in jQuery UI accordion controller at first load.
There after normal behavior.
Accordion default code.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by two tabs

Comment: <div id="accordion">
      <h3>Section 1</h3>
       <div>
          Tab 1
       </div>
      <h3>Section 2</h3>
       <div>
          Tab 2
       </div>
      <h3>Section 3</h3>
       <div>
          Tab 3
       </div>
      <h3>Section 4</h3>
       <div>
          Tab 4
       </div>
    </div>

On apage load Tab 1 & Tab 2 need to open and Tab 3 & Tab 4 collapsed. There after when user clicks any tab it should trigger the normal Accordion behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own accordion without using JQuery UI. Function for open one tab in accordion:

```
        activeContent = $(".accordion > div:has(" + /*item's text*/ + ")"); //your submenu item

        activeContent.show();
        activeContent.siblings("div:visible").hide();
        activeContent.prev("h3").addClass("active");
        activeContent.prev("h3").siblings("h3").removeClass('active');
        $(".accordion > div p").removeClass('selected');
        $(".accordion > div " + /*item's text*/).addClass('selected');
```

And structure html should be:

```
    <div class="accordion">
        <h3 class="subMenuItemHeader">Header1</h3>
        <div>
            <p class="submenuItem">Submenu item 1</p>
            <p class="submenuItem">Submenu item 2</p>
            <p class="submenuItem">Submenu item 3</p>
        </div>

        <h3 class="subMenuItemHeader">Header2</h3>
        <div>
            <p class="submenuItem">Submenu item 1</p>
            <p class="submenuItem">Submenu item 2</p>
            <p class="submenuItem">Submenu item 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So you'll be able to open two tabs in accordion.

Comment: Hi Any
I need to activate two main sections in accordion.